# Excel to firebase using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am creating an attendance website using Reactjs.

I want teachers to upload their student details as an excel file and then I want that to be uploaded to firebase so that I can compare the students ID from firebase and the Students who signed up and sort them out accordingly.

Is there any react component that would allow me to do that. Anything is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the format you are outputting the Excel file in.

Currently i'm working a react project, with both Firbase realtime-db and storage, where we have to parse CSV files, and map the data from those. If you export your Excel file as CSV, i recommend looking at [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/). That was fairly easy to use, with easy to read [documentation](https://www.papaparse.com/docs). I know this won't solve your entire issue, but i hope it can help you in the right direction.